# how to write sumif with changing the criteria and sum range for each row in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am a new beginner of VBA and I am trying to write a sumif function in each row of column D but will change the criteria and sum column range for each row until the last value of the criteria column.

For example: start from row 4, the first sum & criteria range will be 4:4, the second one will be 4:5 and the third one will be 4:6, etc.

I want the answer should be looked like the example below but it only show 8 for those row with "x" in column A.

Dose anyone have any idea to make it show as column D in the example below.

Worksheet:

```
column A B C D E
4      x   1 1
5      x   2 3
6      y   1  
7      y   3 
8      z   4 
9      x   5 8
```

Code:

```
llistrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Source).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row - 1
For i = 4 To llistrow Step 1
    revisedbudget1314 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf( _
        Arg1:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Source).Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(i, 1)), _
        Arg2:="x", _
        Arg3:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Source).Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(i, 3)))
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter this formula in cell `D1`

```
=IF(A1="x", SUMIF(A$1:A1, "=x", C$1:C1), "")
```

and just multiply it for the other cells of column `D` (select `D1` and double click on the small rectangle in lower right corner)

Please use better tags for your questions (e.g. `excel` or `spreadsheet`) so more people can look at them.